# Powershell: Find any value in a CSV column and replace it with a single value

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file where I have to find any non-blank value in 2 specific columns and replace them with 'Yes'

My data looks like this where it can have either both blank, value in either column, or in both.

| Letter Grade | Numeric Grade |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
|  |  |
|  | 10 |
| C | 5 |

I want it to look like this when I'm done

| Letter Grade | Numeric Grade |
| --- | --- |
| Yes |  |
|  |  |
|  | Yes |
| Yes | Yes |

I have 2 problems, addressing columns that have a space in the name (tried wrapping with `"` and `'` and `{`) and regex to match any non-empty value.  It works with the code below to simply replace `a` and if the column is `Letter` instead of `Letter Grade`.

I tried `.+` to match anything in the cell, but I get no matches.
Thanks in advance!

```
Import-Csv -Path ".\test.csv"| ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Letter -eq 'a') {
        $_.Letter = 'Yes'
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv .\poop2.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 2):

You could handle this programmatically by, first, collecting all property names from the first object (done via accessing of intrinsic member [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#psobject) in this example) and then enumerating each property of each object coming from the pipeline and checking if it matches `\S` (any non-whitespace character).

```
Import-Csv path\to\csv.csv | ForEach-Object { $isFirstObject = $true } {
    if($isFirstObject) {
        $properties    = $_.PSObject.Properties.Name
        $isFirstObject = $false
    }
    foreach($property in $properties) {
        if($_.$property -match '\S') {
            $_.$property = 'Yes'
        }
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv path\to\newcsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If, instead of programmatically gathering the object's property names, you wanted to use specific / hardcoded properties, the code would be simpler:

```
$properties = 'Letter Grade', 'Numeric Grade'
Import-Csv path\to\csv.csv | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($property in $properties) {
        if($_.$property -match '\S') {
            $_.$property = 'Yes'
        }
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv path\to\newcsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you Santiago!  That worked perfectly!  You saved the day!